# Formik and Yup - oneOf validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

There are two fields - string and array. How can I write a test function for a field that has a string in it. Tried writing 'test' function, it doesn't work correctly. Tried to use oneOf - it doesn't work either. I think I just wrote them wrong. I can hardly imagine how to fix it

And when the date field is empty it triggers a "required" error for the prod field. Maybe the right thing to do would be to make two yup.objects - one for each field?

```
    const myArray = useMemo(() => someData.map(({ value }) => value), [someData]); // string[]
    
    const schema = yup.object({
      prod: yup
       .string()
       .ensure()
       .oneOf(myArray, 'not in list') // not work
       .required('add prod') // triggers for every field :(
       .test( // not work
         'prod',
         'not in list 2',
         () => !!myArray.find((prod) => prod === myForm.values.prod)
       ),
       date: yup.array().required().min(1, 'add date').length(2, 'add second date'),
   });
```

**To simplify the question:**
Just need a scheme to validate two fields.

The first field is a string (must not be empty and must correspond to a string from a given array of strings).

The second field is an array of two dates (must not be empty, and must contain two dates). Advice on how to do this?